# CASE statement in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table containing these values:

```
object        particular     
-----------------------
AD            hammer  
AD            stone
PD            nail
PR            rocket
OBR           trophy
```

by using a CASE statement how can I select both AD and PD ? Here's what I did:

```
object = CASE WHEN 'PD' OR 'AD' THEN 'PD' AND 'AD' ELSE 'OBR' END
```

I know this is wrong, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Don't you just want to `SELECT object, particular from <tablename> where object = 'AD' OR object = 'PD'`?

Comment: i just want to know how can i do it using the case statement when the parameter = true then it will display both values from like AD and PD :)

Comment: So if we understood correctly, you just want to select the rows from the table where `object` is AD or PD. Correct?

Comment: yups..i want to display both data from AD and PD..by using case statement :)

Comment: @yoyieyoyie please mark an answer here or update accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just use an OR condition in your select?

```
SELECT object 
FROM table_name
WHERE object = 'AD' OR object = 'PD'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN object = 'AD' or object = 'PD' 
               THEN ...
               ELSE ... 
       END AS <newColumnName>
FROM <table>
```

Comment: after the THEN keyword..i put 'PD' and 'AD'..and it gives me error..is that even possible ? :)

Comment: @yoyieyoyie - you need to put the entire implementation into the question for us to look into it

Answer (score 0):

object = CASE WHEN 'PD' OR 'AD' THEN **'PD' AND 'AD'** ELSE 'OBR' END

```
CORRECT SYNTAX:     
CASE WHEN <condition> THEN
    <value1>
    ELSE
     <value2>
    END
```

You have an incorrect syntax in the higlighted part